# jQuery attribute selector in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm getting mixed reactions from people using a certain form on my website. They Use <s>IE7</s>, some internet Explorer prob IE6.
And they get a javascript error saying that the object doesn't support this method, on row 31.

On row 31 I get this code:

```
#31   naam = $("input[name='geb']").val();
```

The corresponding html (through php) is obviously:

```
<input type='hidden' name='geb' value='34' />
```

Does this error mean jQuery is not able to locate my input field through the attribute selector?

Version: jQuery v1.9.1
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gc4KQ/

Comment: Then should it not be `$("input[name='geb']")` ?

Comment: of course your name doesn't match.

Comment: Whoops typo in the question. Offcourse the two names match. In Safari and Firefox it works..

Comment: you better use id's anyway, much more direct selection ! with your code what jquery will do if I'm not mistaken is loop through an array of inputs, looking for the one with the proper attribute. While using ids goes directly to the desired element.

Comment: And the question that is asked all the time, what version of jQuery?

Comment: Check this post: It _might_ be useful: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ie7-odd-bug-with-val

Comment: I ran the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/x8PCN/show/ in IE7 and it works fine.

Comment: try `var naam = $("input[name='geb']").val();`

Comment: Another case of IE ID and NAME situation. Add ID to your elements to match names.

Comment: Have you tried swapping the single-quotes and double-quotes, using the same quotes in both places but escaping the inner quotes, removing the quotes around the value, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Is this another case of Internet Explorer ID and NAME situation ?

Add ID to your elements to match names.

```
<input type='hidden' id='geb' name='geb' value='34' />
```

Come back quick to see if this is your case.

Find a way to open [this updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gc4KQ/1/) in IE